# Javascript animation: IE vs other browsers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, safari

Before I launch into the specifics of the issues I am facing, I just need to ask: Is it a mistake to use IE8 as the reference for building a website, particularly one that uses JavaScript animation? I ask because I have written a fairly simple animation page, mostly from scratch, even with my weak grasp of HTML and JavaScript languages, using IE8 to monitor the progress. I have tweaked the code so that it works just fine in IE8 (compatibility mode turned off), but when I tried it in Safari and Chrome, it does some weird hiccuping in the animation.

I find a lot of questions with the opposite problem: that it works well in everything but IE. So I am wondering, should I be using a different browser for my reference? Or is there a better approach to make it compatible with all browsers? It's so frustrating (as I am sure most of you will agree) to have to deal with the different interpretations of the different browsers.

Thanks for any help!

p.s. I have not coded yet for Mozilla.

Comment: Who is your target audience (i.e., which browsers must this run well on?)

Comment: How are you implementing the animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ie8 as a reference from a performance point of view is not a bad idea, since it has weak js and rendering performance. Using ie7 is even better.

Cross browser compatibility wise, it doesn't matter what you use - unless you use a crossbrowser library like jQuery as your base for the animations you will have to write specific code for the various js and render engines.

Even if you use a library like jQuery, you will still run into rendering issues since the various html/render engines are different across browsers. chrome/safari uses webkit, firefox uses gecko etc.

*The only way to do it right is to start your project by defining what browsers you wish to support and then test what you do in all of them while you are developing your code.*

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing animations, I encourage you to take advantage of css transitions instead of controlling the elements via javascript - you'll have an opportunity to take advantage of graphics hardware as well as more efficient drawing of pixels in general.

If you need to still perform animations in browsers that don't support those css transitions ( some in ie9, none in ie6-8) then you can use a tool like modernizr to detect what's available and control those elements in the event those features aren't available.

Typically, the animations are extra - so I've had good success in ditching the animations for IE users - if you're making slow, javascript driven animations just to work for IE users, you're punishing users that are using better browsers.

Just my $0.02 of course

Comment: The OP obviously needs to support at least IE8 and IE9 and there are no CSS transitions in any version of IE, so I have no idea why you're recommending CSS Transitions as a solution for them.  I've implemented javascript-based animations in IE versions as old as IE6 with success so with the proper implementation, there is no reason why many animations can't work in IE.  It is important to use tweening and dynamically adapt to the speed of the rendering in the host browser to maintain consistent animation speed (generating more frames on faster browsers, fewer frames on slower browsers).

Comment: As someone who's built tech demos using css3 transitions for IE10 I can guarantee versions if IE have various compatibilities.. oh, and this: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform - also, there's some filter crap in ie7/8 that's useful like transforming and scaling. I get what you mean, and the application matters - that's why i recommended the JS fallback in the event the faster, smoother css transitions are applicable.

Comment: OK, I'll amend my comment to say that there are no `released` versions of IE that support CSS transitions. I wouldn't wish IE filters on anyone.  I've written a lot of slideshow transitions using them and they are quite the pain to use for anything other than trivial use (like don't try mixing opacity fades with fonts).

Comment: If you looked at the web-resource I posted, IE9 ( a released version ) supports css transforms, just not 3d transforms.

Comment: if you read what I wrote, I'm talking about `CSS transitions` which is generally what is needed for animations.  Can you show me any IE9 code that does a nice slideshow with transitions like fade, wipe, etc... using CSS3 only?  Here's your own reference for transitions: http://caniuse.com/#search=transition.

Comment: Ah, gotcha - how do you feel about using JS as a fallback for older IE's? Re: the point of using CSS transitions in browsers that support them

Comment: I already use JS as a fallback.  I use CSS3 when it exists.  If it doesn't exist and I'm in IE, I use filters and if neither of those is an option, I use JS to do the animations manually.  That isn't what your answer proposed.  You proposed ditching animations in browsers that don't support CSS transitions which is not what the OP wanted at all.  I think I'm done discussing this with you.  I think you know your stuff, but your answer doesn't help the OP with their question which is what I was trying to point out.